# I am providing a key for each child in react, but I am still getting an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have done this before and I am providing a key, but for some reason I am still getting the error. I am a bit new to react so it could be a silly mistake somewhere.

Edit: Error is the each child in an array should have a unique key

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

class BooksList extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return _.map(this.props.books, book => {
      return (
        <div key={book.id}>
          <h2>{book.title}</h2>
          <h3>{book.description}</h3>
          <h4>{book.price}</h4>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    books: state.books
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BooksList);
```

Edit:

I tried binding `this.renderList`, in the constructor, but still have the same issue:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting. I think its a binding issue, you should bind the renderList function and that should help

Comment: What specific error are you getting?  I'm assuming it's the one about "each child in an array must have a unique 'key' prop".

Comment: Also, are you sure that the book ID values are unique?

Comment: @markerikson, good catch, that could also be a problem

Comment: The error is the each child in an array must have a unique 'key' prop, let me try to bind the function and book id is unique, it shows 1, 23, 223.

Comment: I tried binding this.renderList in the constructer and still same issue.
I did 
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
  }

Comment: Can you show us the log of `this.props.books` ?

Comment: Try using the lodash index instead of `book.id`. e.g. `return _.map(this.props.books, (book, index) => ....` then replace `book.id` with `index`.

Comment: I [can't reproduce this](https://jsfiddle.net/1fbjtout/). (As an aside, why are you using lodash when you can just do `this.props.books.map`?)

Comment: Okay this.props.books gives back an object that looks like {2: object, 23: object, 223: object} each of those objects are the 'books'. I tried using the lodash index instead of book and no luck. Also I am using lodash so I can map through an object not an array.

Comment: I am getting this on the error also,
   in div (created by BooksList)
    in BooksList (created by Connect(BooksList))
    in Connect(BooksList)
    in Provider

Comment: @TaylorAustin can you create a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue so we can test it?

Comment: The log is also logging before the error: and empty books object. 
It looks like Object{book: Object} , but nothing is inside of it. Then at the end of the log is where I see the Object {2: object, 23: object, 223: object}

Comment: what is `the log` ?

Comment: I will add the github REPO to make this easier:
https://github.com/tbaustin/test_react_redux

Comment: try changing your key to be this.. `_.map(this.props.books, (book, key) => {` then ```<div key={`${book.id}-${key}`}>```

Comment: I think the problem is that this.props.books is an empty object at first and then somehow it is filled later on. I am not sure how though.

Comment: @TaylorAustin Yes, if you look at what you are doing.. `componentDidMount` is where you say load the data.. but think about that function name.. did mount. it has already mounted.. thus it has already done a render cycle.. and it has tried to render the books. If you did it before the mount then you would have them on initial render :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you are not loading the books before the map happens initially.. so you have invalid data initially.

Initially `this.props.books` is this

[image: Initially this.props.books is this]

then you load the books and it turns to this.
[image]

The fix for this is to only render when you have a valid object. Use the lodash isEmpty check for an object... use a forEach so you dont return empty in an array (less items to hold in array). and then just return that array at the end :)

```
renderList() {
  const elems = [];
  _.forEach(this.props.books, book => {
    if (_.isEmpty(book)) return;
    elems.push(
      <div key={book.id}>
        <h2>{book.title}</h2>
        <h3>{book.description}</h3>
        <h4>{book.price}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return elems;
}
```

Comment: Taylor, let me help you with your dev tools. Its very hard to test your code with how it currently is. Do you know about debugging and how to debug the code?

Comment: Uh... the initial approach of using `_.map()` _should_ actually be valid, in two ways.  `_.map(undefined)` will return an empty array, and `map()` should generally be preferred over `forEach()` for this sort of work.

Comment: @markerikson Its not undefined though. Look at the images I posted.. whats happening is `_.map({book: {}})`

Comment: Lemme rephrase that a bit.  I was addressing possible behavior _if_ `props.books` was actually undefined on initial render. The other odd bit here is that `books` is an object, and not an array.  I'm curious why the data is structured that way.

Comment: @markerikson the data structure is defined by the OP, as to why it is not really sure. but you can see [here](https://github.com/tbaustin/test_react_redux/blob/master/src/reducers/booksReducers.js) that the reducer returns an object as default state for books... and then [here](https://github.com/tbaustin/test_react_redux/blob/master/src/components/pages/booksList.js) you can see where the books are used.